# Fetching data from MQTT server using ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to fetch data from a MQTT server using react.js and TypeScript.
The server sends data from a robot every 100ms.
I've already tried npm install mqtt.

I don't have much experience with MQTT, i just want to fetch the data from it

```
import React from "react";
import * as mqtt from "mqtt";

function App() {
  let client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://test.mosquitto.org");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    client.on("connect", function () {
      client.subscribe("presence", function (err: any) {
        if (!err) {
          client.publish("presence", "Hello mqtt");
        }
      });
    });

    client.on("message", function (topic: any, message: any) {
      // message is Buffer
      console.log(message.toString());
      client.end();
    });
  }, []);

  return <> MQQT </>;
}

export default App;
```

The error is
**constants.js:46 Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
at ./node_modules/mqtt-packet/constants.js (constants.js:46:1)**

How can I handle this properly?

import mqtt from 'mqtt';
expected data to be fetched

Answer (score 0):

When using *vite* or *webpack*, the import is different:
`import * as mqtt from 'mqtt/dist/mqtt.min'`

It's all documented: https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js#vite